# Parallel Execution of multiple threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to execute multiple instances of my class concurrently. i have written the following code below. I have done it in two ways. But I don't see the difference. What is the right way to have parallel running threads?

Thanks.

Here the snippet:

```
public class MyClass {

        public MyClass() {
            runnable = true;
        }

        public boolean isRunnable() {
            return runnable;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            /* METHOD 1
             MyClass myclass = new MyClass();

             if (myclass.isRunnable()) {
                 for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
                     myclass.execTask();      
                     Thread.sleep(sleep);
                 }
             }
             */

                  //METHOD 2
            final MyClass myclass = new MyClass();


            ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNo);

            for (int i = 0; i < threadNo; i++) {
               threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
                        myclass.execTask();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(sleep);
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            threadPool.shutdown();

            public void execTask(){
            .........
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: in parallel, or concurrently?

Comment: BTW: `myclass.execTask;` does nothing - you should at least be using `myclass.execTask();`.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between your two methods is that in "Method 2," you may actually have multiple threads of execution (assuming that `threadNo` is greater than 1).  Method 2 allows for multiple work threads to grab a `Runnable` and call `execTask` (by calling `run`) in parallel (concurrently, to be precise).  The pause in "Method 2" does pretty much nothing.

"Method 1" executes entirely on the "Main" thread.  It calls `execTask`, waits, and then calls it again.  This will call the execution some number of times serially.

(I assume this is pseudo-code because parts of it won't compile.)

Here is a cleaned-up "Method 2".  Note that I have `threadNo` worker threads (it helps if this is larger than 1) and I create `loop` `Runnables`.

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNo);

for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
    threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { myclass.execTask(); });
}
```

Comment: so I can remove the sleep? if I Loop only once, I see only one Task being executed. I still thought the threadpool submit would start all 'threadNo' threads concurrently..

Comment: I edited the answer to make the proper use of Method 2 a little clearer.

Comment: Thanks.Just to be clear, when does one want to have several "runnable" Tasks? Is the case when Runnable is 1, all the threads compete to execute the one Runnable and only one gets to?

Comment: You want to use this kind of multithreading when each call to `execTask` does a single, independent piece of work.  By placing these pieces of work on a queue and allowing them to be worked concurrently, you should be able to get them done faster than if you do them one at a time.

Comment: that execTask actually does some file handling. Can I be sure that Access to the file would be mutually exclusive?

Comment: You can use synchronization to make sure that file access is exclusive.  This raises the question of whether multithreading is helpful.  If the file access is a small part of your task, then it might be OK.  If the file access dominates your task, you will find that your multithreading adds little.  The key is that the more independent your task is, the better multithreading works.